# OBJLoader error "class constructors must be invoked with 'new' Although it is being invoked with new

Tags: three.js

I am facing a serious issue with three.js
Being facing this issue in my old production project plus even when I am trying to create a sample test project. I want to import an OBJ model. Here are all my codes.

In the main index.php file I am using this method to invoke threejs
`<script type="text/javascript" src="build/three.js"></script>     <script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>`

This is the app.js file
`import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';

```
        import { OBJLoader } from './threejsm/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
        import { MTLLoader } from './threejsm/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js';

        let container;

        let camera, scene, renderer;

        let mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        let object;



            // manager

            function loadModel() {

                // object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                //  if ( child.isMesh ) child.material.map = texture;

                // } );

                
            }

            const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( loadModel );

            manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                console.log( item, loaded, total );

            };




        init();
        animate();
```

function de3d(){

```
const loader = new OBJLoader( manager );
    loader.load('models/male02.obj', function (obj){
        scene.add(obj);
    });
```

}

```
        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 250;

            // scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
            camera.add( pointLight );
            scene.add( camera );




            // model

            function onProgress( xhr ) {

                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

                    const percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( 'model ' + Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

                }

            }

            function onError() {}
```

de3d();

```
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

I even have followed the docs repeatedly, wasted a lot of nights, and stuck on this "one" error. I have even tried using nodejs, angular, etc all possible variations of ES6 import and stuff.

The OBJLoader won't just import my files. One of my project has suddenly stopped working at the time of release. I got back to the project after a year and now it has stopped working.

I tried using both the latest version {r138} and the old version {r132}

Can someone please help?

I tried importing the obj, gltf, fbx, all the loaders are giving away "class constructors must be invoked with 'new'" whereas the loader is being called with the new keyword

Answer (score 0):

This error usually indicates a version mismatch in your project. Meaning application or third-party code is using ES5 code syntax for deriving from built-in classes which is not compatible with latest `three.js` releases.

Make sure that *all* `three.js` classes like loaders, controls, exporters etc. are from the same release like your core library.

More information here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/class-constructors-must-be-invoked-with-new/31870